# I am trying to get words be displayed in their own row so one word under each other

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dictionary

I have an array of words being passed to a component and trying to display each word underneath each other in input tags but they are being displayed next to each other[image]

my file:

```
const Words = ({arr}) => {

let num = ((100/arr.length) - (1)).toString() + '%';
console.log(arr)
return (
    <div>

        {arr.map((letter, idx) =>{
            return(
                <input 
                    className="letters" 
                    type='text' 
                    key={idx} 
                    style={{width: num}}
                />
            )
        })}

        <br/>
    </div>
)
```

}

CSS file:

```
    .letters{
    display: flex;
    float:left;
    margin-left: 2px;
}
```

my main file:

```
    const App = () => {
  let words = ['Hello', 'World']
  return(
    <Container className="main-content">
      {words.map((word) =>{
        return(
          <Words arr={word.split('')} />
        )
      })}
    </Container>
  );
}
```

CSS file:

```
    .main-content{

  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: don't float left then

Comment: Makes no sense to `display: flex;` an `<input>` element. Also forget about `float`s. Use it only when you know exactly what you're doing. Use flexbox instead.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove `float`s and `display: flex` from your INPUT elements
- Use `flex-direction: column;` on the parent element